# Different email validation results for different socks5 proxies

Tags: python, sockets, smtp, email-validation, socks

I am using  [Gardener's Library](https://github.com/Gardener-gg/email-verifier)   for validating email with socks5 proxies.

When using `188.166.83.17:1080` output is :

```
{'address': Address(name='', addr='om.parikh107950@marwadiuniversity.ac.in', username='om.parikh107950',
domain='marwadiuniversity.ac.in'), 'valid_format': True, 'deliverable': True, 'full_inbox': False,
'host_exists': True, 'catch_all': True}
```

When using `78.46.218.20:13414` output is :

```
{'address': Address(name='', addr='om.parikh107950@marwadiuniversity.ac.in', username='om.parikh107950',
 domain='marwadiuniversity.ac.in'), 'valid_format': True, 'deliverable': False, 'full_inbox': False, 
'host_exists': True, 'catch_all': False}
```

The used email for the above test is INVALID.

1. Why different proxies are giving different outputs for the same email?
2. From `deliverable`, `full_inbox` and `catch_all`, which factor or combination of factors I should rely on and why?

Comment: Hey, I am curious as to where you purchased the SOCK proxy. Can you make any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why different proxies are giving different outputs for the same email?

Mail servers employ IP based blacklists in order to catch spam from botnets etc. It might be that one of the proxies you use is on such a blacklists while the other is not.

> From deliverable, full_inbox and catch_all, which factor or combination of factors I should rely on and why?

It is unclear what you want to do in the first case with the library. But if you want to know if an email is valid than it will not work reliably, no matter which field from the result you look at. Mail servers commonly employ IP based black lists so the results might differ depending from which source IP you send. Mail servers also use [Greylisting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greylisting_(email)) which means that the first attempt to send might fail but the second succeed, i.e. a ´deliverable`of`False`might be wrong. Mail server can also fail delivery at various stages so a`deliverable`of`True` might be wrong too.

In general, there is no reliable way to verify an email address apart from trying to send to this address and expecting the recipient to acknowledge that the mail got received.

Comment: Thanks!, is there any way I can check if socks5 IP I am using is blacklisted or not? if I confirm my IP with Spamhaus is it sufficient?

Comment: @hack3r_0m: There are many blacklists, both free and proprietary ones. While you can check if a specific IP address is on some specific public blacklist you don't know if it is on some private one and you especially don't know which blacklists the mail server is using. Blacklists can also be dynamic, i.e. if too much spam or connection attempts to verify an email come from a specific IP it might be temporarily blacklisted just by this specific mail server.